# SyntaxError: unmatched ) in regular expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I have this component called **hours**, an input field where the user can either type the hours or click an arrow on over or on click (up or down):

```
  <SquareInput
            type="number"
            pattern="\d*"
            min="0"
            step="1"
            onChange={(e) => {
              const value = e.target.value;
              const updatedValue = regexHours.test(value)
              if (updatedValue > 24 || updatedValue < 0) {
                return;
              } else {
                setHours(value);
              }
            }}
            value={hours}
          />
```

I want to let the user type:

1. Numbers not symbols (from 0 to 24)
2. Maximum 2 digits

But in this current way the user can type 4 digits and symbols as well, I was thinking that maybe a regex would solve the problem such as: `const regexHours = '/^((?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])(?:.d{1,2})?|25(?:.00?)?)$)/';` But I have no clue how to implement it and if it is the right approach. All the things I tried by using SO gave me errors.

While for the **Minutes component**:

```
<SquareInput value={minutesDuration} />
```

I will the have same issues but instead I want to show:

1. Numbers not symbols (from 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09 10 etc. etc. to 59)
2. Maximum 2 digits not 4.

And I found this regex: `const regexMinutes = '[0-9]|[1-5][0-9]';`

Any ideas how to tackle the problem? currently I get ***SyntaxError: unmatched ) in regular expression*** To give a better idea how the components look like here below you will find a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You have a paranthesis after `$` in your regex. remove it. You can check your regex in [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Also a regex literal should not be quoted; it's just `/stuff/`.

Comment: You have 4 `(` and 5 `)` in the regex.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, by removing the extra ) the error disappeared but I can still type symbols for some reasons and up to 4 characters instead of 2. I tried to use so many regex but nothing seems working. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression like this:

```js
const reHours = /^[0-1][0-9]$|^2[0-4]$/

console.log(reHours.test('12'))
console.log(reHours.test('19'))
console.log(reHours.test('05'))
console.log(reHours.test('22'))
console.log(reHours.test('29'))
console.log(reHours.test('34'))
console.log(reHours.test('1a2'))
console.log(reHours.test('b12'))
console.log(reHours.test('q12'))
console.log(reHours.test('12@'))
console.log(reHours.test('1'))

const reMinutes = /^[0-5][0-9]$/
```

```
<SquareInput
            type="number"
            pattern="\d*"
            min="0"
            step="1"
            onChange={(e) => regexHours.test(e.target.value) ? e.target.value : ""}
            value={hours}
          />
```

Comment: Hi Sinan, thanks a lot. Sorry for the ignorance but how would I implement it in my code if the value is the input from the user?

Comment: Edited the answer, you should define your regexHours and regexMinutes of just replace the regexHours with the regex provided: `/^[0-1][0-9]$|^2[0-4]$/.test(e.target.value)`. Btw, you don't need to say sorry, this is a place to get help and learn :) I hope this helps, happy coding

Comment: Thanks a lot, It seems now that the only thing the user can add is a comma ->  ,
Not any other symbols not numbers either letters. But instead I would need only numbers from 0 to 24 for hours and for minutes from 00 to 59. Max 2 digits

Comment: I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-glade-p0cei?file=/src/App.js) that you can test, it validates `onBlur`. I believe you can use this to meet your needs.

Comment: Hi Sinan, thanks a lot. I tried but I kind find a regex that both works. For hours, I just need an input field that allow only 2 digits, no symbols and number from 0 to24. Any regex i tried is not working. And for minutes, only 2 digits, no symbols and number from 00 to 59. Do you have any clue how to achieve that?

Comment: That is what my regex is doing. Do you want to prevent users even entering that as input? My codesandbox will not accept it `onBlur` if it is not in that format. Check the codesandbox link again, I think this will meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the hours works perfectly but not the minutes, you can still type letters and symbols inside and that should be prevented. Like just 2 digits and only numbers from 00 to 59

Comment: Look into my codesandbox, you can't type anything other than numbers between 00-59. Glad it helped, kindly accept the answer if you think this solved your problem :)